# OBTENER EL VALOR CORRECTO SIN REPETIR VALOR EN LA MISMA FILA SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Estoy intentando tener el valor de una comisión de acuerdo a la venta de unos artículos, el calculo de los datos me da bien, lo que no he podido hacer es solo mostrar el valor del porcentaje al que pertenece la venta y mostrar los demas valores en cero

Esta es mi consulta.

```
SELECT num_factura, n_numero_documento_rc, totalcontable,
       valor_pagado, total_dcto, porcentaje_dto, fecha_documento, fecha_ultimo_mvto, nombre_cliente, cantidad_unidades, valorunitario, dcto_porcentaje_valor_unitario,
       precio_real_unitario,nombre_grupo, codigo_articulo, nombre_articulo, nombre_vendedor, observaciones_recibo,
 CASE
        WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   52000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.06 )
        WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   49000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.06 )
        WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   69000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.06 )
        WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   59000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.06 )
        --WHEN V3.valorunitario   =   49000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.06 )
        --WHEN V3.valorunitario   =   59000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.06 )
        WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   54000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.06 )
        WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   53000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.06 )
        WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   44000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.06 )
        --WHEN V3.valorunitario   =   52000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.06 )
        WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   65000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.06 )
        WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   43000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.06 )
        --WHEN V3.valorunitario   =   49000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.06 )
        WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   40000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.06 )
        --WHEN V3.valorunitario   =   40000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.06 )
       ELSE 0 end as precio_al6,
       CASE WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   50000 and V3.valorunitario <= 51999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.05 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   47000 and V3.valorunitario <= 48999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.05 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   67000 and V3.valorunitario <= 68999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.05 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   57000 and V3.valorunitario <= 58999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.05 )
            --WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   47000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.05 )
            --WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   57000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.05 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   52000 and V3.valorunitario <= 53999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.05 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   51000 and V3.valorunitario <= 52999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.05 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   43000 and V3.valorunitario <= 43999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.05 )
            --WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   50000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.05 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   63000 and V3.valorunitario <= 64999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.05 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   39000 and V3.valorunitario <= 42999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.05 )
            --WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   47000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.05 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   38000 and V3.valorunitario <= 39999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.05 )
            --WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   38000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.05 )

       ELSE 0 end as precio_al5,
       CASE WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   49000 and V3.valorunitario <= 49999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.04 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   46000 and V3.valorunitario <= 46999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.04 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   66000 and V3.valorunitario <= 66999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.04 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   56000 and V3.valorunitario <= 56999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.04 )
            --WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   46000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.04 )
            --WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   56000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.04 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   51000 and V3.valorunitario <= 51999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.04 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   50000 and V3.valorunitario <= 50999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.04 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   42000 and V3.valorunitario <= 42999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.04 )
            --WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   49000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.04 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   62000 and V3.valorunitario <= 62999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.04 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   38500 and V3.valorunitario <= 38999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.04 )
            --WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   46000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.04 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   37000 and V3.valorunitario <= 37999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.04 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   36000 and V3.valorunitario <= 37999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.04 )

       ELSE 0 end as precio_al4,
       CASE WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   48000 and V3.valorunitario <= 48999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.03 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   45000 and V3.valorunitario <= 45999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.03 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   65000 and V3.valorunitario <= 65999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.03 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   55000 and V3.valorunitario <= 55999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.03 )
            --WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   45000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.03 )
            --WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   55000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.03 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   50000 and V3.valorunitario <= 50999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.03 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   49000 and V3.valorunitario <= 49999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.03 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   41000 and V3.valorunitario <= 41999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.03 )
            --WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   48000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.03 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   61000 and V3.valorunitario <= 61999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.03 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   38000 and V3.valorunitario <= 38499 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.03 )
            --WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   45000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.03 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   36000 and V3.valorunitario <= 36999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.03 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   35000 and V3.valorunitario <= 35999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.03 )

       ELSE 0 end as precio_al3,
       CASE WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   47000 and V3.valorunitario <= 47999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.02 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   44000 and V3.valorunitario <= 44999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.02 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   64000 and V3.valorunitario <= 64999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.02 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   54000 and V3.valorunitario <= 54999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.02 )
            --WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   44000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.02 )
            --WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   54000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.02 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   49000 and V3.valorunitario <= 49999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.02 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   48000 and V3.valorunitario <= 48999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.02 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   40000 and V3.valorunitario <= 40999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.02 )
            --WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   47000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.02 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   60000 and V3.valorunitario <= 60999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.02 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   37500 and V3.valorunitario <= 37999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.02 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   44000 and V3.valorunitario <= 44999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.02 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   35000 and V3.valorunitario <= 35999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.02 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   34000 and V3.valorunitario <= 34999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.02 )

       ELSE 0 end as precio_al2,
       CASE WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   46000 and V3.valorunitario <= 46999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.01 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   43000 and V3.valorunitario <= 43999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.01 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   63000 and V3.valorunitario <= 63999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.01 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   53000 and V3.valorunitario <= 53999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.01 )
           -- WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   43000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.01 )
            --WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   53000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.01 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   48000 and V3.valorunitario <= 48999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.01 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   47000 and V3.valorunitario <= 47999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.01 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   39000 and V3.valorunitario <= 39999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.01 )
            --WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   46000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.01 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   59000 and V3.valorunitario <= 59999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.01 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   37000 and V3.valorunitario <= 37499 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.01 )
            --WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   43000     THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.01 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   34000 and V3.valorunitario <= 34999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.01 )
            WHEN V3.valorunitario   >=   33500 and V3.valorunitario <= 33999 THEN convert(decimal(10,0),V3.precio_real_unitario * 0.01 )

       ELSE 0 end as precio_al1
       FROM (
                  SELECT sc_codigo_fuente,
                         k_sc_codigo_fuente_fac,
                         k_sc_codigo_fuente_rc,
                         num_factura,
                         n_numero_documento_rc,
                         TotalContable,
                         valor_pagado,
                         total_dcto,
                         convert(numeric(10, 2), total_dcto / TotalContable)                                   as porcentaje_dto,
                         fecha_documento,
                         d_fecha_documento_rc                                                                  as fecha_ultimo_mvto,
                         nombre_cliente,
                         cantidad_unidades,
                         Valorunitario,
                         convert(numeric(10, 0), Valorunitario * total_dcto / TotalContable)                   as dcto_porcentaje_valor_unitario,
                         convert(numeric(10, 2), Valorunitario - (Valorunitario * total_dcto / TotalContable)) as precio_real_unitario,
                         codigo_articulo,
                         nombre_grupo,
                         nombre_articulo,
                         nombre_vendedor,
                         observaciones_recibo
                  FROM (
                           SELECT vf.sc_codigo_fuente,
                                  k_sc_codigo_fuente_rc,
                                  k_sc_codigo_fuente_fac,
                                  num_Factura,
                                  n_numero_documento_rc,
                                  vf.TotalContable,
                                  convert(numeric(38, 0), valor_pagado)     as valor_pagado,
                                  d_fecha_documento_rc,
                                  (TotalContable - valor_pagado)            as total_dcto,
                                  vv.Fecha_Documento,
                                  vv.Nombre_Cliente,
                                  vv.Cantidad_Unidades,
                                  convert(decimal(10, 0), vv.Valorunitario) as Valorunitario,
                                  g.sc_detalle_grupo as nombre_grupo,
                                  vv.Codigo_Articulo,
                                  vv.Nombre_Articulo,
                                  vv.Nombre_Vendedor,
                                  v1.sv_obs_rc as observaciones_recibo

                           from (
                                    select k_sc_codigo_fuente_rc,
                                           k_sc_codigo_fuente_fac,
                                           vd.n_numero_documento_fac as num_factura,
                                           CASE
                                               WHEN k_sc_codigo_fuente_rc = 'RC' AND k_sc_codigo_fuente_fac = 'RM'
                                                   THEN sum(vd.n_valor_pagado)
                                               else 0 end            as valor_pagado,
                                           d_fecha_documento_rc, n_numero_documento_rc,sv_obs_rc
                                    from v_documentos_pagos_detalle vd
                                         --where k_sc_codigo_fuente_rc = 'RC'
                                    group by vd.n_numero_documento_fac, k_sc_codigo_fuente_rc, k_sc_codigo_fuente_fac,
                                             d_fecha_documento_rc,n_numero_documento_rc,sv_obs_rc
                                ) v1
                                    inner join v_bi_mvto_venta vv on Numero_Documento = v1.num_factura
                                    inner join v_documentos_facturas vf on v1.num_factura = vf.n_numero_documento
                                    inner join articulos a on vv.Codigo_Articulo = a.k_sc_codigo_articulo
                                    inner join grupos g on a.ka_ni_grupo = g.ka_ni_grupo
                           where vv.Pagada = 'S'
                             and ISNULL(vf.TotalContable, 0) > 0
                             and a.ka_ni_grupo in (318,
308,
333,
334,
325,
326,
331,
336,
280,
309,
305,
338,
279,
317,
323,
316)
                       ) V2
                  where v2.k_sc_codigo_fuente_rc = 'RC'
                    and v2.k_sc_codigo_fuente_fac = 'RM'
                    and v2.sc_codigo_fuente = 'RM'
                    and Nombre_Vendedor not in ('ADMON')
                    and Cantidad_Unidades > 0
                    and Nombre_Cliente not in ('ADMON')
              )V3
order by Fecha_Documento desc
```

dentro del CASE WHEN estoy estableciendo los rangos de precios unitarios de los artículos asociados. lo que intento hacer es algo como así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo necesito que me muestre el valor de la comisión según el precio vendido e intentado agregando los **CASE WHEN** dentro del select pero el resultado no me da, porque como muestra la imagen, me salen mas valores dentro de la misma fila, cuando solo debería calcular uno solo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien intente crear otra subconsulta mas y puse esto, pero no he obtenido el resultado esperado

```
    CASE WHEN precio_al6 > precio_al5 THEN precio_al6
            WHEN precio_al6 > precio_al4 THEN precio_al6
            WHEN precio_al6 > precio_al3 THEN precio_al6
            WHEN precio_al6 > precio_al2 THEN precio_al6
            WHEN precio_al6 > precio_al1 THEN precio_al6
       ELSE 0 end as precio_al6,
  CASE WHEN precio_al5 > precio_al6 THEN precio_al5
            WHEN precio_al5 > precio_al4 THEN precio_al5
            WHEN precio_al5 > precio_al3 THEN precio_al5
            WHEN precio_al5 > precio_al2 THEN precio_al5
            WHEN precio_al5 > precio_al1 THEN precio_al5
       ELSE 0 end as precio_al5,
       CASE WHEN precio_al4 > precio_al6 THEN precio_al4
            WHEN precio_al4 > precio_al5 THEN precio_al4
            WHEN precio_al4 > precio_al3 THEN precio_al4
            WHEN precio_al4 > precio_al2 THEN precio_al4
            WHEN precio_al4 > precio_al1 THEN precio_al4
       ELSE 0 end as precio_al4,
  CASE WHEN precio_al3 > precio_al6 THEN precio_al3
            WHEN precio_al3 > precio_al5 THEN precio_al3
            WHEN precio_al3 > precio_al4 THEN precio_al3
            WHEN precio_al3 > precio_al2 THEN precio_al3
            WHEN precio_al3 > precio_al1 THEN precio_al3
       ELSE 0 end as precio_al3,
              CASE WHEN precio_al2 > precio_al6 THEN precio_al2
            WHEN precio_al2 > precio_al5 THEN precio_al2
            WHEN precio_al2 > precio_al4 THEN precio_al2
            WHEN precio_al2 > precio_al3 THEN precio_al2
            WHEN precio_al2 > precio_al1 THEN precio_al2
       ELSE 0 end as precio_al2,
  CASE WHEN precio_al1 > precio_al6 THEN precio_al1
            WHEN precio_al1 > precio_al5 THEN precio_al1
            WHEN precio_al1 > precio_al4 THEN precio_al1
            WHEN precio_al1 > precio_al3 THEN precio_al1
            WHEN precio_al1 > precio_al1 THEN precio_al1
       ELSE 0 end as precio_al1
```

Alguien podría guiarme de como hacerlo de una forma mejor?

Comment: Haces una tabla con los rangos (superior e inferior) y con el factor. Luego haces un join usando between

Comment: Gracias, voy a intentar @Yussef

Comment: Tus expresiones CASE no tienen mucho sentido. Todas las condiciones regresan el mismo valor excepto el ELSE.

Comment: si, así es @LuisCazares tiene ya habia notado esa cuestion para poder identificar porque pasaba, y vienen siendo muy ambiguas por cuestion de que hay rangos que se repiten. sin embargo no se de que forma lograr este objetivo

Comment: Lo que necesitas es compartir la lógica que sigues para decidir en que columna deben de aparecer. Los rangos abiertos de precio_al6 se sobreponen a los otros rangos.

Comment: @LuisCazares la logica comienza apartir del calculo que hay en 
convert(numeric(10, 2), Valorunitario - (Valorunitario * total_dcto / TotalContable)) as precio_real_unitario
que es el precio unitario cuando se aplica un descuento a los articulos vendidos, porque afecta su valor unitario real. entonces en el case when por eso le indico el rango de precio, porque es el que la empresa define por cada articulo. entonces este es un calculo de comision para liquidar a los vendedores su respectiva comision.